# hasOne Relation not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent

Hi I want to make relationship between two tables first Table is **product** and second is `productimages`

**ProductController.php**

```
public function product(){
     $products = Product::all();
     dd($products->images);
}
```

**Product.php (modal)**

```
class Product extends Model
{
      public $timestamps = false;
      //

      public function images()
      {
         return $this->hasOne(ProductImage::class);
      }
 }
```

**ProductImage.php(model)**

```
class ProductImage extends Model
{
    public function product(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

When i am using this method `$products = Product::find(1);` working find but i need all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `$products->images` you're trying to access property of collection.

Preload all products with their images, use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$products = Product::with('images')->get();
```

Then you'll be able to get image of each product and avoid N + 1 problem:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    // Access $product->image here
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Product::with('images')->get();
```

Comment: if you want all images of all products you can use `map`
`$images = Product::with('images')->map(function($p) { return $p->images; });`

Comment: Note: here `with` is used for eager loading, It means you are loading all images along with all products.

Comment: Sorry! I was using my phone to answre I forgot to use `get` function
`$images = Product::with('images')->get()->map(function($p) { return $p->images; });`

Comment: i am not getting all images each product